# Proof that exists a bijection between $X$ and $\mathcal P (A)$.

Tags: set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets such that $\exists h: B \to A$ an injective function, $A$ is infinite and $B$ has at least two differents elements.

Denoting by $X = \{f: A \to B \, | f \, \text{ is a function} \}$, proof that exists a bijection between $X$ and $\mathcal P (A)$.

My attempt: By Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem, it's sufficient showing that exists an injection $X \to \mathcal P (A)$ and an injection $\mathcal P(A) \to X$.

By hypothesis, exists $b_1, b_2 \in B$ s.t. $b_1 \neq b_2$. Consider

\begin{align*}
\Phi: \mathcal P (A) &\to X\\
Z &\mapsto f_Z(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
b_1, \, \text{if } x \in Z
\\ 
b_2, \, \text{if } x \notin Z
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align*}

If $\Phi(Z_1) = \Phi (Z_2),$ i.e. $f_{Z_1} (x) = f_{Z_2} (x), \forall x \in A$. Then, 
$$x \in Z_1 \Rightarrow b_1 = f_{Z_1} (x) = f_{Z_2} (x) \Rightarrow x \in Z_2.$$
$$ x \notin Z_1 \Rightarrow b_2 = f_{Z_1} (x) = f_{Z_2} (x) \Rightarrow x \notin Z_2. $$

Hence, $Z_1 = Z_2$ and $\Phi: \mathcal P (A) \to X$ is injective.

I'm with difficult to find an injection $X \to \mathcal P (A).$

Help?

Comment: Hint: A function $f:A\to B$ is a subset of $A\times B$. Do you know that there is a bijection between $A\times B$ and $A$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't know how to construct such bijection between $A \times B$ and $A$.

Comment: Well, you can't necessarily "construct it." Do you know there is a bijection between $A\times A$ and $A$, if $A$ is infinite?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I do.

Comment: So we can easily create an injection from $B\times A\to A\times A$. And we can find an easy injection $A\to B\times A$, so we get an injection $A\times A\to B\times A$.

Comment: How woulde be the injection from $B \times A \to A \times A$?

Comment: From the injection $B\to A$.